# How does Chartbeat measure Server Load Time?

Tags: download, timing, chartbeat

It seems that Chartbeat is reporting my Server Load Time incorrectly.

Does anyone know how Chartbeat measures this data so I can make this metric more accurate?

Answer (score 2):

chartbeat server load time is a measure of how long time it takes to load the HTML from your server, from servers on the east coast US.

http://chartbeat.com/faq/

Answer (score 1):

From Chartbeat: [How fast is my site? What information do I get from Load Times?](http://support.chartbeat.com/entries/22900343-How-fast-is-my-site-What-information-do-I-get-from-Load-Times-)

> ### User Page load
>
> ...
> It is calculated by timing the two pieces of Chartbeat javascript on the site. This
> means it includes all the Javascript and embedded items you have on the page and tells
> you how long it's taking to load on the user's browser.

If the load times look incorrect, check to make sure that you have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var _sf_startpt=(new Date()).getTime()</script>
```

In the head of your page before loading your other resources, and the other code they give you just before the body closes.

Comment: Linked reference is dead and can't find a reference to this on their current documentation. Is this entry still necessary (wondering since I'm dealing with some legacy code which is using it)?